Cannot locate ACM for Nitro Enclaves AMI using aws cli
Running the command with a specific image id works:
aws ec2 describe-images --image-id ami-01c4415fd6c2f0927 --region us-west-2 --query 'sort_by(Images, &CreationDate)[-1].{Name: Name, ImageId: ImageId, CreationDate: CreationDate, Owner:OwnerId}' --output json --region us-west-2 --profile <profile-name>
Outputs:
{ "Name": "ACM-For-Nitro-Enclaves-1-0-2_ 2021-04-29T21-09-41.751Z-3f5ee4f8-1439-4bce-ac57-e794a4ca82f9-ami-028ce88e069714286.4", "ImageId": "ami-01c4415fd6c2f0927", "CreationDate": "2021-04-30T00:01:19.000Z", "Owner": "679593333241" }
However when I try to perform a query it does not work
aws ec2 describe-images --owners 679593333241 --filters "Name=name,Values=ACM-For-Nitro-Enclaves*" --region us-west-2 --query 'Images[*].[ImageId]' --output json --region us-west-2 --profile <profile-name>
AWS has a special service amsskms cli however I cannot get it for some reason.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managedservices/latest/userguide/find-ami.html
I was expecting to query all the AMIs so I could write some automation.
